# Null Object When Passing Parameters To Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing

I have taken the Asp.Net account registration controller and view model and have tried to change them a bit to do the following.  After a user has registered his account, he gets redirected to a next page with two check boxes where he will have to select if he wants to be a seller or a buyer.  Upon submission he will be assigned a number in the database.  Here is the code I have so far:

ViewModel

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 8)]
    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    //[Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
    public DateTimeOffset UserDOB { get; set; }

    public int? UserRole { get; set; }
    public AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool buyer { get; set; }
    public bool seller { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Controller for the registration:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, ApplicationUser test)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, UserDOB = model.UserDOB };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                return RedirectToAction("Choice", "RoleSelection", new { Id = Guid.NewGuid()});
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }


        return View(model);
    }
```

Now here is where I get stuck.  The code does not work.  I believe there is a problem with the string Id parameter or model holding the information  from the user.  All I want to do is pass that single value to the datatable:

```
   public ActionResult Choice(string Id)
    {
        using (var db = new FoundationEntities())
        {
            var trans = db.AspNetUsers.Where(x => x.Email == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            return View(trans);
        }
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Choice(RegisterViewModel model, string Id)
    {
        using (var db = new FoundationEntities())
        {
            if (model.buyer == true && model.seller == false)
            {

            var work = db.AspNetUsers.Where(x => x.Email == User.Identity.Name).Select(x => x.UserRole);
                model.UserRole = 3;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            if (model.seller == true && model.buyer == false)
            {
                var work = db.AspNetUsers.Where(x => x.Email == User.Identity.Name).Select(x => x.UserRole);
                model.UserRole = 2;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: Well, `model` is *certainly* going to be `null` after that redirect, since there's nothing passing that information to the next action.  But are you saying that `Id` is also `null`?  Can you debug in your browser to see what the actual redirect URL is?

Comment: Considering the subject, my guess is that you are hitting the Controller method, but I'm not entirely sure that is happening. Can you be a little more descriptive as to what the problem is and what your question is? Are you hitting the Controller method with a breakpoint? Which params are null, etc.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly.  So maybe I need to be passing the model through the redirect?  can i do that?

Comment: Not a lot of your code makes sense. Your view model should not contain `AspNetUser AspNetUser` nor `int Id` (your registering a new user so those things don't even exist yet). And what is the `ApplicationUser test` parameter in your POST method for? Then you redirect to the `Choice()` method passing it an new `Guid` which has no relationship to anything (what is it for and you never use it anyway?). From that you then post back `RegisterViewModel` but you view is not based on `RegisterViewModel`

Comment: And is a user is either a 'buyer' or a 'seller' then why do you have 2 `bool` properties - you do not even take into acount the case where the users checks both checkboxes. And why do you need a separate view just to choose this anyway (as opposed to just including it in the initial view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that there is a type mismatch between the route param, what you are passing and the expected model.

In `Register` you pass an anonymous object with a `Guid` `Id` to `Choice`. But `Choice` expects a model expects of type `RegisterViewModel` and a `string` `Id`.

One way to fix it would be to change your `Choice` signature to

```
Choice(RegisterViewModel model, Guid Id)
```

And your call to `RedirectToAction` with

```
RedirectToAction("Choice", "RoleSelection", new {model, Id = Guid.NewGuid()})
```